# What does "God" mean?

Tags: terminology, names-of-god

Muslims call God Allah. Jews call him JHWH, Christians call Him God. The name has even become the word to point to entities that are gods.

Who has given God this name? Does it come from the Greek "theos"? In French "God" is "Dieu" and in Italian it is "Dio". Is God even a name? Like Allah in Islam and JHWH in Jewish religion?

There are even suggestions it derives from the word "good". In almost all languages God is pronounced the same. In Dutch it's called God too. The word for "good" is "goed" in Dutch. Is God even a name? Or is it used in Islam too? To say that the name of God is Allah. What is the name of God in Christianity? Does it even have a name? In some interpretations God is not a superbeing of the human kind eventhough He created us in His own image. It is more a Holy Ghost.We can use the term "God" to refer the Greek Gods. But what does it mean? Good for being good? Does it refer to a superhuman being? A holy ghost?

Im not sure why this is off-topic. Because it can cause doubt? There is even a tag "names of god".

Comment: English etymology questions belong at [english.se].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127983/discussion-on-question-by-deschele-schilder-what-does-god-mean).

Comment: @GratefulDiscipleThanks for commenting in chat but I cant use chat. Still the question remains, if God is the title Lord then I think of things like Duches and Baron or Sir. What if "He" is a spirit? Can a spirit be a father (this meaning comes closest I guess)?

Comment: @curiousdanni I dunno, my curious friend. Dont you think Christians know the best. God is not only named God in English. In many countries its name is God.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I only now see the extent of your comments in chat! I am still a bit sleepy... I think you have made it perfectly clear what I mean! Thanks for that. I think father comes closest.

Comment: @4castle I cant chat. So... Wouldnt it be a sign of respect to call my child like that?

Answer (score 1):

God is not a name.  God is a title.  The Bible calls the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob by many different names, and these names tell us something about his character.  The full list is in this article: https://www.gotquestions.org/names-of-God.html

The various names/titles of God were initially written in Hebrew.  Here are a few significant names:

> ELOHIM [el-oh-heem]: God “Creator, Mighty and Strong” (Genesis 17:7; Jeremiah 31:33) – the plural form of Eloah, which accommodates the doctrine of the Trinity. From the Bible’s first sentence, the superlative nature of God’s power is evident as God (Elohim) speaks the world into existence (Genesis 1:1).

> ADONAI [ˌædɒˈnaɪ; ah-daw-nahy]: “Lord” (Genesis 15:2; Judges 6:15) – used in place of YHWH, which was thought by the Jews to be too sacred to be uttered by sinful men. In the Old Testament, YHWH is more often used in God’s dealings with His people, while Adonai is used more when He deals with the Gentiles.

> YHWH / YAHWEH / JEHOVAH [yah-way / ji-hoh-veh]: “LORD” (Deuteronomy 6:4; Daniel 9:14) – strictly speaking, the only proper name for God. Translated in English Bibles “LORD” (all capitals) to distinguish it from Adonai, “Lord.” The revelation of the name is given to Moses “I Am who I Am” (Exodus 3:14). This name specifies an immediacy, a presence. Yahweh is present, accessible, near to those who call on Him for deliverance (Psalm 107:13), forgiveness (Psalm 25:11) and guidance (Psalm 31:3).

When God spoke to Moses He introduced himself as

> I AM WHO I AM. This is what you are to say to the Israelites: ‘I AM has sent me to you’ (Exodus 3:14).

> The phrase translated “I am who I am” in Hebrew is ehyeh asher ehyeh. The word ehyeh is the first person common singular of the verb to be. It would be used in any number of normal situations: “I am watching the sheep,” “I am walking on the road,” or “I am his father.” However, when used as a stand-alone description, I AM is the ultimate statement of self-sufficiency, self-existence, and immediate presence. God’s existence is not contingent upon anyone else. His plans are not contingent upon any circumstances. He promises that He will be what He will be; that is, He will be the eternally constant God. He stands, ever-present and unchangeable, completely sufficient in Himself to do what He wills to do and to accomplish what He wills to accomplish.  Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/I-AM-WHO-I-AM-Exodus-3-14.html

> Due to a fear of accidentally taking God’s name in vain (Leviticus 24:16), the Jews basically quit saying it out loud altogether. Instead, when reading Scripture aloud, the Jews substituted the tetragrammaton YHWH with the word Adonai (“Lord”). Even in the Septuagint (the Greek translation of the Old Testament), the translators substituted Kurios (“Lord”) for the Divine Name. Eventually, the vowels from Adonai (“Lord”) or Elohim (“God”) found their way in between the consonants of YHWH, thus forming YaHWeH. But this interpolation of vowels does not mean that was how God’s name was originally pronounced. In fact, we aren’t entirely sure if YHWH should have two syllables or three.  Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/YHWH-tetragrammaton.html

Comment: We called our dog Elohim. Ello in short. What does the title entail? What does it cover? I know what a Professor is but a God?

Comment: You will find a full explanation here: https://www.gotquestions.org/names-of-God.html

Comment: What does 'God" mean? Lord?